# jQuery next() didn't work in my case

Tags: jquery

I want to traverse from start to target

```
<a class="start">
   <span></span>
</a>
<div class='target'></div>
```

and I use this line

```
$(this).next('.target')
```

$(this) refers to span. am I traverse correctly?

Comment: yes.... you need to give more context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `this` is the `span`, it has no siblings, so `next` will not work. To get to the `.target` div, you need to go up a level in the DOM, then use `next`. Try this;

```
$(this).parent().next(); // = the `.target` div
```

Alternatively you can use `closest()` with a selector:

```
$(this).closest('a').next();
```

Comment: should I specify the class name?

Comment: You can if you would like to, `next` will take a selector. It all depend on how often you plan on changing your HTML markup. Personally, I'd add the class selector.